# How would we maintain an unbroken line of communication with a moon base?

Tags: science-based, space, moons, communication, logistics

If we had to keep a channel for lunar communication with modern technology such that it was always open regardless of earth-moon positioning, how would we do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All you need is three ground stations, about 120 degrees of longitude apart. We're greatly assisted by the Moon being tidally locked, so assuming the base is on the near side it will never be out of line-of-sight with the Earth. NASA already do this for their [Deep Space Network](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA_Deep_Space_Network), in the US, Spain and Australia.

Comment: I was going to give the same answer. But you beat me to it. Excellent answer. I was going to add to have them 60 degrees apart for redundancy to increase reliability of communication.

Comment: A case of been there, done that, and by the 1960's too. Clever little human beings!

Comment: Also, don't forget that the poster hasn't specified WHERE the lunar base is.  For absolute Lunar coverage (covering the Dark Side too), you need either a small constellation of satellites orbiting the moon or a couple at various Lagrange points.

Comment: @aphenine I think laying a cable from the near side would be cheaper and easier.

Comment: @MikeScott Only in a stable and developed Lunar society.  If you can get to the Moon regularly to maintain and service a base, communication satellites are vastly more viable than a cable and vastly cheaper.

Comment: A bit of trivia is that Neal Armstrong's walk on the moon was received by the Park Observatory in Australia and then sent around the world. No US observatory was within line of site at that moment.

Answer (score -2):

I forget the terminology, but scientists have discovered an (x) particle (x because I can't remember what it's called) that operates on a sub-space film that exists throughout the universe. Regardless of the distance or line of sight, flipping one bit of the (x) particle simultaneously flips its paired bit in another part of the universe thus creating real-time sub-space instantaneous communications; if we can only harness this capability.

I also see this as a possible remote power creation device if the (x) particles could be combined in such a way to enlarge them, or possibly putting them in series to create just enough micro power for computer equipment.

- A powered device on Earth flips the bits at a rotational speed and the paired bit drives a generator to create power at the remote location.

Are we there yet? No, but it's in our future. Do we pursue it now or wait another 50-100 years to decide to create this technology?

~Raptor

Comment: You appear to be talking about quantum entangled particles, and there is much more nuance to the so called action-at-a-distance.  These are usually involved in quantum encryption, but this still involves conventional communication between the two people with the entangled particles..  You can't transmit any information using just the entangled pairs (this would break causality).